# how to use serilog to log handled exceptions from anywhere/globally in a .NET Core 3.1 application (using serilog SQL Server sink)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, exception, serilog

I'm developing a custom logging mechanism for an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app with angular front end. I'm using serilog to log errors and successful events in the MS SQL Server.

So far so good, the logger works and everything is fine. This is achieved by a custom action filter used on the controllers to log (with attribute). In cases of unhandled exceptions the logger logs the error just fine.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to log handled exceptions (within a try/catch block) due to the fact that there are nested try catch blocks inside functions called from EF Core repositories we use.

One solution is to write an explicit logging method in each controller. This is not the best practice but it works.

If I create a separate class and I call a logging method from that class anywhere in the controllers, the logger does not write to the database.
Long story short, if there are 3 method calls, lets say, from other classes inside a method invoked, which they in turn contain a try/catch block, how can I log an exception, if raised ?

I'm asking this because in case 2 out of N functions raise an exception, the application will continue to work, but I need to know what went wrong in order to fix it. Please let me know if you need a code sample or anything else that can help.

I've tried a global exception handling mechanism with middleware as proposed after a search in google, but its the same as using an action filter from what I've seen so far and with the same results.

Below I'm pasting some of the logic implemented on how to log and handle exceptions in a case of an error during POST/PUT/DELETE operations.

in the base controller we use the attribute of the action filter implemented

```
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(LoggingActionFilter))]
    // POST: api/[controller]
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult<TEntity>> Post(TViewEntity entity)
    {
        // do stuff...
    }
```

the **LoggingActionFilter** handles the request sent to the server and logs the action performed.

In the **Startup.cs** file we have the following

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services added....
        services.AddScoped<LoggingActionFilter>();
    }
```

The **LoggingActionFilter** class

```
public class LoggingActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public LoggingActionFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<LoggingActionFilter>();
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var userId = GetUserId(context.HttpContext);
        var isOnRequest = true;
        try
        {
            //before execution                
            var requestBody = GetRequestBodyAsString(context);

            _logger.LogInformation(/*params*/);

            var result = await next();

            //after execution
            isOnRequest = false;

            _logger.LogInformation(/*params*/);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             _logger.LogError(/*params*/);
        }
    }

    private string GetUserId(HttpContext context)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.User.Identity;
        var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        return claim?.Value;
    }

    private string GetRequestBodyAsString(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        foreach (var element in context.ActionArguments)
        {
            result += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(element.Value);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The logic above works as intended and the attributes decorate the REST actions in the base controller since they are overridden in the derived classes.

It will catch the unhandled exceptions (without try/catch block).

In a case of handled exceptions however, since there can be a method which calls, lets say 3 other methods that do have a try/catch block, in case one or more of the 3 methods stated above fail, the program will continue to respond but I need to log each error. Is there a proper way to do so with a global exception handler? Any tips ?

Please let me know if you need any further information from me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like you trying to catch generic exceptions in your controllers, which is an antipattern most often. And remember that you can always rethrow you exception if needed. And there are global exception handlers where you can handle your unhandled exceptions. Can you share some code sample?

Comment: What we are doing is actually, logging all REST actions except GET, (we log the last one in a case of error) in order to be able to keep track of actions performed by the users. Now, for the purposes stated above we went with the solution of action filters and decorated the base class actions with the proper attribute. The action filter, logs the action performed and in a case of error, logs the error as well. I will add further clarification for the issue including some sample code a bit later, if this can be of any further help. Thank you in advance

Comment: @AndrewSilver I have updated the question as requested. Please let me know when you see it.